# Разложись строку на отдельные буквы и присвоить их каждую в отдельный элемент

Tags: java

Задача такая: есть строка, нужно разложить ее побуквенно и каждую букву в правильном порядке слова присвоить в другие String.

```
String main;
String one; // здесь первая буква из main
String two; // здесь вторая буква из main
String three; // здесь третья буква из main
и т.д.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое:

```
one = String.valueOf(main.charAt(0));
two = String.valueOf(main.charAt(1));
```

и т.д.

Comment: А если размер исходной строки постоянно разный?

Comment: Значит нужно создать массив строк.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как поможет массив строк.
        Вот у меня получается и это не очень красиво.

        String one = "";
        String two = "";
        String three = "";

        if (main.length() == 1) {
            one = String.valueOf(main.charAt(0));
        } else if (main.length() == 2) {
            one = String.valueOf(main.charAt(0));
            two = String.valueOf(main.charAt(1));
        }

Comment: @Deepstack Если не поняли, учите программирование по книгам, а не вопросам на SO. Все равно не поймете. А так, в рамках контекста на вопрос я ваш ответил.

Comment: ну, ок, но то что вы ответили это я и так знал.